# Write a function that takes a list of integers, but only returns those that are NOT multiples of 5

Tags: python

Write a function filter_mult5 that takes a list of integers called numbers, and returns another list that contains all the integers in numbers which are not multiples of 5:

```
def filter_mult5(numbers):
    return #a list of all numbers that are not a multiple of 5
```

For example, `filter_mult5([4,6,8,10,12])` should return `[4,6,8,12]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a so called list comprehension and filter out the multiples of five by using the modulus operator (multiples of five yield zero if passed to the modulus operator) as follows:

```py
def filter_mult5(numbers):
    return [n for n in numbers if n%5 != 0]

# Test
>>> filter_mult5(list(range(12)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11]  # 0, 5, 10 are filtered
```

Comment: Please add explanation as well